# Error when trying to use Open Tok with Swift

Tags: swift, flutter, opentok, vonage

I try to use the Open Tok library in Swift through the Flutter platform channel to call the native IOS code.

`[ERROR] rumor_client_v1.c:274 - otk_rumor_v1_client_send (pClient == NULL) rumor client is not initialized and cannot send message`

Can't figure it out what is causing it.

I tried to test their sample but I'm getting the same error. Even a clean/new project is resulting in the same.

Current setup:

`*********************** OpenTok iOS SDK **************************** **** Version/Revision: ios-2.22.3/86d684fa2c49c335cc63ce5c52f57fd8610db130 **** Library built on: May 17 2022 **** Copyright 2022 Vonage **** Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 ****`
Xcode 14.1 on mac os 12.6

My code :

```
print("initSession")
let args = call.arguments as! [String: Any]
let apiKey = args["apiKey"] as! String
let sessionId = args["sessionId"] as! String
let token = args["token"] as! String
var error: OTError?
let session = OTSession(apiKey: apiKey, sessionId: sessionId, delegate: self)!
print("My session id" + session.sessionId)
// try to connect to the session with the token
session.connect(withToken: token, error: &error)
if let error = error {
print("Error connecting to session: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

result :
`the print of the session returns the session id`

If I find the solution I will post it to you

Comment: Are you on an ARM mac? and can you try the latest version of the SDK, 2.24.0

Comment: yes I use a mac ARM

***** OpenTok iOS SDK | Version/Revision: ios-2.24.0/7316208e3bf83c855acb8a31765dff7b2b6a2b57 | Library built on: Oct 31 2022 | Copyright 2022 Vonage | https://www.vonage.com/legal/communications-apis/terms-of-use/
My session id1_MX40NzAwMDAxNH5-MTY2ODA3MTcyOTQ5***********************
[ERROR] rumor_client_v1.c:274 - otk_rumor_v1_client_send (pClient == NULL) rumor client is not initialized and cannot send message

Comment: Can you try running xcode and the simulator in rosetta mode https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/release-notes.html#issues-using-xcode-simulator-to-preview-your-app-on-a-mac-with-an-m1-chip

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunately it doesn't work but I hadn't thought of doing that.

In my current state the application works well on the simulator I put a button on my interface and when I click I trigger the function

Comment: hi if you are getting the same error using our sample code (https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples-swift/tree/main/Basic-Video-Chat), can you open a ticket with our support (https://video-api.support.vonage.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) and mention the session ID which is erroring.